# Django dictionary key value access

Tags: python, django

I got the below response via api to a text field, how can I access the pin and reference no.. I tried separating it but it's not looking safe I want to be able to access the pin with key "pin"

```
{
  "success":"true",
  "message":"E-pin was Successful",
  "pin":"1211ggg3322",
  "amount":775,
  "transaction_date":"29-03-2023 12:18:33 pm",
  "reference_no":"I11767",
  "status":"Successful"
}
```

This code is saved in a textfield django field under checker model called report

So In the views.py

```
Check=checker.objects.filter(pk=1)
Check= Check.report

Now if I do 
Print(Check.pin)
```

I get err:str object has no attribute 'pin' error

Comment: If your `dict` is called `d`, access it with `d['pin']`. Otherwise, I'll need more info to help. Please show the code you've tried, pared down to a [mre].

Comment: This still isn't a [mre]. You will get much better answers by providing information adequate to reproduce the problem. What is the output of `print(Check.report)` prior to assigning `Check.report` to `Check`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Postgre SQL database, you can have json model field and store whole json response for field. You can query and update json field using Django ORM.
But in this case your api response is stored as string. You need to load model field in json.loads and then you have dictionary and get values normally as dict.get() or dict['key'].

Comment: Found that out the hard way but thanks for the update